# Laravel - best way to update huge amount of data from request?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an ecommerce application developed using laravel. Every day I want to update an amount of products from external api (request).

Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "0564",
    "amount": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "4235",
    "amount": 24
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "27683",
    "amount": 646
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "code": "457",
    "amount": 44
  },
]
```

Below laravel function in controller:

```
public function import(Request $request)
    {
        $products = $request->all();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $currentProduct = Product::where('code', $product['code'])->first();
            if ($currentProduct) {
                $currentProduct->amount = $product['amount'];
                $currentProduct->update();
            }
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Above code is working, but it is slower. Is there any best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You Can Use




       public function import(Request $request)
            {
                $products = $request->all();
        
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                 Product::where('code', $product['code'])
                ->update(['amount'=>$product['amount']]);
                }
        
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'success',
                ], Response::HTTP_OK);
        }
```

Comment: Result time is same

Answer (score 1):

if you are using (Laravel >= 8.x) there is a method named upsert. The method's first argument consists of the values to insert or update, while the second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table. The method's third and final argument is an array of columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database.

try something like this:

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    foreach (array_chunk($data, 500) as $products) {
        $updateData = [];
        foreach($products as $value) {
            $currentProduct = Product::where('code', $value['code'])->first();
            if ($currentProduct) {                
                $updateData[] = [
                    'code' => $value['code'],
                    'amount' => $value['amount'],
                ];
            }
        }

        Product::upsert($updateData, ['code'], ['amount']);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Comment: I am using laravel 6.12